# intersection of decreasing compact sets is again compact

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I am following a real analysis course and I would like to discuss some definitions and results about metric spaces.

First of all, the definition of compact set. I the course we defined it as follows:

A subset $A$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ is called compact if for every open cover of $A$ there exist a finite sub-cover.

Why such a definition ? It doesn't seem natural to me.

The next question is about an exercise. Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and consider a decreasing sequence of compact subsets $X \supset A_0 \supset A_1 \supset ...$, then show that ${\bigcap}_{i=0}^{\infty} A_i$ is again compact.

Is it sufficient to show that ${\bigcap}_{i=0}^{\infty} A_i$ is bounded and closed ? If yes, then ${\bigcap}_{i=0}^{\infty} A_i$ is closed because any intersection of closed sets is again closed and ${\bigcap}_{i=0}^{\infty} A_i$ is bounded because it is contained in $A_0$. But if this is true I didn't use the decreasing hypothesis. Where am I wrong ?

Thank you for your help and comments.

Comment: Are you more comfortable with the sequential definition of compactness? If so, could you briefly explain why it seems natural/important to you?

Comment: Generally, compact sets are not those that are bounded and closed: take an infinite set with the discrete topology: any of its infinite subsets is closed and bounded, whereas it is not compact.

Comment: @TheoBendit yes indeed we have seen the definition of sequentially compact. For me it simply means that a sequence in a compact set has to stay in that set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it sufficient to show that ${\bigcap}_{i=0}^{\infty} A_i$ is bounded and closed ?

No, this is not sufficient. There exist sets which are bounded and closed, yet they are not compact. For example, the set $(0,1)$ is abounded closed subset of the space $(0,1)$, yet the set is not compact.

There are two ways I see that you can solve the question:

**Option 1**:
There is a theorem that states that a closed subset of a compact set is compact. This means all you need to prove is that the intersection in question is closed, and since it is a subset of $A_1$, a compact set, you are done.

**Option 2**:
If you cannot yet use the above theorem (this is probably the case, since otherwise, the problem is way too easy), you can just go from definitions. That is, start with an open cover for ${\bigcap}_{i=0}^{\infty} A_i$, and try to find some finite subcover. In order to do that, think about this fact:

*Any open cover of ${\bigcap}_{i=0}^{\infty} A_i$, along with the set $X\setminus {\bigcap}_{i=0}^{\infty} A_i$, is an open cover of $A_1$...*

Comment: Oh I see. Does that means that the result "a bounded and closed subset is compact " is only true in $ \mathbb{R}^n$ ? Actually we have seen the result you mentioned in the Option 1. This would mean that I only have to show that $X \setminus A_0$ is open ? thank you for the comment, it really helped

Comment: @Alain Not only in $\mathbb R^n$, but it's not true in general, that is correct. If you know the result from Option 1, then yes, all you need to show is that $A_0$ is closed, which is simple.

Comment: thank you ! I am a bit confused now, I thought that bounded and closed sets were compact sets. Concerning your Option 2, I thought about taking an open cover of $A_0$, then it would also be an open cover of $\bigcap^{\infty}_{i=0}A_i$, no ? then the finite sub cover of $A_0$ is also a finite cover of $\bigcap^{\infty}_{i=0}A_i$ ?

Comment: @Alain If compact sets were the same as closed bounded sets, then we wouldn't need the complicated definition of compactness. As for option 2, no, you cannot start with an open cover for $A_0$. You must prove that every open cover of the **intersection** contains a finite subcover of that same intersection. However, you can do that by using the cover of the intersection, then modifying it to make an open cover of $A_0$, and then, since you know $A_0$ is compact, there exists a finite subcover of this modified for $A_0$. From that, you can extract the finite subcover of the intersection.